# How to inspect contents of storage.local in Chrome Packaged App?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Is there some way (extension, or special debug option) to inspect contents of [storage](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage.html) in Chrome Packaged App, other than using javascript console?

Resources tab only allows inspection of localStorage/sessionStorage (which is disabled in packaged apps)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

After I've realised that there is really no other option but JS console, I've created [devtools extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-explorer/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb) (took 4 hours to create initial version), which can inspect chrome.storage.

So now there is such tool=)

[Sources](https://github.com/jusio/storage-area-explorer)

Comment: Perfect, save my live

Comment: This is so immensely helpful. Great design and does exactly what it promises, thanks a bunch!

Comment: any update in 2020 ? there is a normal way to inspcet it ?

Answer (score 9):

Try just typing:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

then look in the console.

Comment: Well, I'm asking for if there is some other way.

Comment: Nope. If there were, it'd be a bug.

Comment: @sowbug why it would be a bug?

Comment: The storage is sandboxed and protected from programmatic access except through the API. So it'd be considered a bug if there were some other way to have access to it. Of course, the data lives somewhere on the user's persistent storage, so you can probably track it down on your own machine and look at it with a hex editor.

Comment: @sowbug Well, it is still possible  to create extension for editing storage of any chrome app (I've actually done it, after I've found out that there are no tools like this). You have just to use `devtools.inspectedWindow.eval` and `runtime.sendMessage` APIs to hook into target window storage.

Comment: Cool! You should publish it. I was thinking you were interested in doing it for user data, not just your own data, but if you just wanted a developer tool to run on your own machine, that's a smart approach.

Comment: @sowbug Published https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-explorer/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb