# How to manage chrome.storage for non-experienced users

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I used localStorage (google chrome extension) background page for save extension data (like local extension config). Someone pointed me, that localStorage is synchronous, and better to use [chrome.storage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html), which is asynchronous.

But localStorage has [image]user-friendly interface, non-experienced users (like our QA) can easily check/change content of localStorage:

```
   open extension's background page->"Resources"->"Local Storage".
```

When I use chrome.storage (chrome.storage.sync.set/get), it works ok, but...

*How I can see/change (by mouse and keyboard) extension's chrome.storage content, without scripts in debug console?*

```
  chrome.storage.sync.get({"config": {}}, function(cfg) { 
     console.log("Config is: " + JSON.stringify(cfg, null, '\t'));
  });
```

Comment: Try this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-explorer/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to inspect contents of storage.local in Chrome Packaged App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679828/how-to-inspect-contents-of-storage-local-in-chrome-packaged-app)